# Linking between Square Matrix and Positive Definite Matrix?

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization

I'm not mathematically trained. A module I'm taking this semester needs me to: **Show that a square matrix with only diagonal values that are all positive is a positive definite matrix.**

What is the most layman and simplistic way of answering this question?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you Normal Human for those tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from definition:

A symmetric matrix $A$ is positive defined if  for all non zero vectors $x$ we have $x^T A x >0$.

Let:
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&0&0&\cdots &0\\
0&a_2&0&\cdots &0\\
\cdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots& a_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
 be a diagonal matrix with $a_i>0$
than, for  a vector $x=[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]^T$, we have:

$$
x^TAx=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_2&\cdots &x_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&0&0&\cdots &0\\
0&a_2&0&\cdots &0\\
\cdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots& a_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\\cdots \\x_n\\
\end{bmatrix}=
$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1x_1&a_2x_2&\cdots &a_nx_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\\cdots \\x_n\\
\end{bmatrix}=
a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2+\cdots +a_nx_n^2
$$
that, since $a_i>0$, is a sum of squares, so it is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

Start writing down the defitions: A symmetric matrix is positive definite iff we have for all $x \in \def\R{\mathbf R}\R^n$, $x \ne 0$ that 
$$ x^tAx = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j > 0 $$
If now $A$ is diagonal, that is $a_{ij} = 0$ for $i \ne j$, the sum simplifies (the off-diagonal terms vanish):
$$ x^tAx  = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii} x_ix_i = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}x_i^2 $$
Now note, that for $x \ne 0$, there is some coordinate, $x_k$ say, with $x_k > 0$. As all $a_{ii}$ are positive by assumption, we have 
$$ x^tA x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}x_i^2 \ge a_{kk}x_k^2 > 0 $$
The $\ge$ sign holds as $a_{ii}x_i^2 \ge 0$ for all $i$, the $>$-sign as $a_{kk}>0$ and $x_k^2 > 0$. So $x^tAx > 0$ for $x \ne 0$ and $A$ is positive.